# Add the tensorflow lite static library to the buildroot cross compiler

Tags: tensorflow, static-libraries, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite, buildroot

I work on a Buildroot Embedded Linux System and I have to code Machine Learning Inference using the Tensorflow lite C++ static library. I have already built it following the tensorflow tutorial and I have got my libtensorflow-lite.a file ready to go.

But now, I don't really know how to add this static library to the cross compiler on buildroot. The buildroot user manual doesn't seem to talk about it.
I don't know if I have to create a ".mk" file or a "Config.in" file as a package or not.
Can someone help me ?